# Which java.lang.Class method generates the right input for Class.forName()?

Tags: java, reflection

I would like to write some code like this:

```
Object o = ...;
String oTypeName = o.getClass().getName();

//on the other side of the wire:

Class<?> oClass = Class.forName(oTypeName);
Object oAgain = oClass.newInstance();
```

However, it's not clear from the javadoc which method I should use to initialize `oTypeName`, i.e. which method will produce the expected input to [`Class.forName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-):

- [`getCanonicalName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getCanonicalName--): "Returns the canonical name of the underlying class as defined by the Java Language Specification. Returns null if the underlying class does not have a canonical name (i.e., if it is a local or anonymous class or an array whose component type does not have a canonical name)."
- [`getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--): "Returns the name of the entity (class, interface, array class, primitive type, or void) represented by this Class object, as a String. If this class object represents a reference type that is not an array type then the binary name of the class is returned, as specified by The Java™ Language Specification."
- [`getTypeName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getTypeName--): "Return an informative string for the name of this type."

It's fairly obvious that I don't want either of these:

- [`getSimpleName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName--): "Returns the simple name of the underlying class as given in the source code."
- [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#toString--): "The string representation is the string "class" or "interface", followed by a space, and then by the fully qualified name of the class in the format returned by getName"

I don't expect this to work for primitive types.  It's okay if it won't work for arrays.  The main thing I'm concerned about is nested classes and `Foo.Bar` vs. `Foo$Bar`.

Comment: I do mean nested; question updated

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The definite answer is [`getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--). Although a bit hidden, this is specified in the Javadoc of the overload of [`forName(className, initialize, loader)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-boolean-java.lang.ClassLoader-):

> Given the fully qualified name for a class or interface (**in the same format returned by `getName`**) this method attempts to locate, load, and link the class or interface.

And it is also specified that calling [`forName(className)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-) is equivalent to calling this overload, with default values:

> Invoking this method is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> Class.forName(className, true, currentLoader)
> ```
>
> where currentLoader denotes the defining class loader of the current class.

---

Here's a sample code showing that it works for nested classes, local classes, anonymous class, primitive or object arrays. It won't work for primitives because `Class.forName` doesn't handle primitive classes.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        class LocalClass {}

        System.out.println(Class.forName(name(StaticNestedClass.class))); //static nested class
        System.out.println(Class.forName(name(InnerClass.class))); // inner class
        System.out.println(Class.forName(name(Integer[].class))); // object array
        System.out.println(Class.forName(name(int[].class))); // primitive array
        System.out.println(Class.forName(name(List.class))); // interface
        System.out.println(Class.forName(name(LocalClass.class))); // local class
        System.out.println(Class.forName(name(new Object(){}.getClass()))); // anonymous class
    }

    private static String name(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz.getName();
    }

    public static class StaticNestedClass {}
    public class InnerClass {}
}
```

Comment: And conversely, neither `getTypeName` nor `getCanonicalName` will  work for, for example, primitive arrays.  Both `Class.forName(int[].class.getTypeName())` and `Class.forName(int[].class.getCanonicalName())` will throw `ClassNotFoundException`, but `Class.forName(int[].class.getName())` will not.

Comment: Thanks for finding that buried javadoc reference -- that's the official word I was looking for and couldn't find!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like either `getName()` or `getTypeName()` works, at least in the simple case:

```
public final class ForNameTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Object o = new Foo();
        System.out.println("class is: " + o.getClass());

        for(String getterMethodName : Arrays.asList("getName", "getTypeName", "getCanonicalName")){
            Method m = Class.class.getMethod(getterMethodName);
            String oTypeName = m.invoke(o.getClass()).toString();
            System.out.println(getterMethodName + " yields " + oTypeName);
            try{
                Class<?> oType = Class.forName(oTypeName);
                Object oAgain = oType.newInstance();
                System.out.println(" ... and it works: " + oAgain);
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.err.println(" ... and it fails: " + e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Foo{}
}
```

The output produced is:

```
class is: class ForNameTest$Foo
getName yields ForNameTest$Foo
 ... and it works: ForNameTest$Foo@4554617c
getTypeName yields ForNameTest$Foo
 ... and it works: ForNameTest$Foo@74a14482
getCanonicalName yields ForNameTest.Foo
 ... and it fails: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ForNameTest.Foo
```

Comment: That's exactly where I got to as well. Wow, you think you know something (I was **sure** it was `Foo.Bar`) and then you go to test it and, well....

Answer (score 1):

I always use getCanonicalName() Internal objects (like your Foo$Bar If static public vs inline implementation) will be able to be constructed as well.

Also you can make it work w/ primitives .. 'int.class' for example does exist. However you'll probably have to do a check on the primitives classes, and make the Object instance (Integer vs int) then call the accessor like intValue().  Because of this i use a lot of Object instances vs primitive, but that's just my preference I guess.

Answer (score -1):

```
Object oAgain = oClass.newInstance();
```

[EDIT]
No Matter which method(getName(), getCanonicalName(), etc..) you **cannot** use newInstance() method to create an object for a non static inner class

If you are creating an object using newInstance(), then it is mandatory that the underlying class contains a no arg constructor. Even if we explicitly insert one no argument constructor, the compiler will convert it to a constructor with some arguments(Only in case of a non static inner class)

[END EDIT]

Below is the link for brief code that i found. It demonstrates the explanation above.

http://thecodersbreakfast.net/index.php?post/2011/09/26/Inner-classes-and-the-myth-of-the-default-constructor

Comment: It's not necessary that the no-arg constructor be the default constructor, actually.

Comment: Edited the answer, what I mean is newInstance() method expects a no argument constructor to be present in your class.